# text editor in c using video memory

Tags: c++, c

I am creating text editor using C. Can you explain these macros?

```
#define Ad (unsigned char far *)0xb8000000
#define Pos(y,x) (2*((y)*80+x))
#define Write(y,x,ch) *(Ad+Pos(y,x))=ch
#define WriteA(y,x,fb) *(Ad+1+Pos(y,x))=fb
```

Comment: I'd add the tag `computer-archeology`... :)

Comment: Where did you copy that stuff from ? Must be a very ancient editor.

Comment: This is a very bad design that will be useless on almost any modern machine.

Answer (score 7):

Back in the dark ages of console programs, people used to output text by writing directly to the screen buffer.

The console screen buffer is organized as a continuous array of pairs of bytes, describing the displayed character and its attributes (color, background color, and eventually blinking).

In your case, the screen buffer seems to be at 0xb800000 (`Ad`). `Pos` translates a screen position `(y,x)` to a memory offset in the screen buffer, assuming a screen width of 80.

`Write` changes the displayed character at the specified position, while `WriteA` changes the character's color.

Comment: On my first home computer, the console screen buffer was just one byte per position.  It wasn't even a full byte, since one bit was missing.  Kids these days.

Answer (score 4):

My goodness, it's like 1990 all over again...

- Ad is the address of the section of memory which the video card (in text mode) maps onto its character generator.   So if you write an ASCII 'A' to *Ad, then you'll get an 'A' at the top left of the screen.
- Pos is a macro which calculates an offset from the top left of the screen for an x,y position.  (It's a dangerously broken macro, because there are no () around the 'x'.)
- Write writes a char to an (x,y) position
- WriteA writes character attributes (color, etc) to an (x,y) position.

I don't want to be harsh, but you're going to struggle to write a text editor if you're struggling at this level.

Answer (score 3):

- Ad return the address of the beginning of the video memory
- Pos translate a x, y position into an absolute position in memory (assuming 80 chars width)
- Write put the character ch at the x,y position
- WriteA set the font color at the x,y position

Comment: Specifically, Pos translates assuming an 80 column display.

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to use them.

Those macros are for old hardware, where the screen could be accessed directly.

- the first macro just specifies the base address of the screen (and `far` is not recognized by the Standard C)
- the second macro converts a screen position to an offset
- the 3rd one writes a character to the screen
- the 4th one writes a colour to the screen

Again, **you do not want to use those macros**.

Comment: You can still use these on modern hardware, just not always with a modern operating system.

Comment: Hmm ... does the BIOS POST write directly to 0xb8000000 ... interesting doubt: just got myself something to do for the weekend :)

Comment: 0xb8000000 is not the same as b800:0000. The latter, which is the segmented 16-bit address for VGA text memory, maps to 0x000b8000.

Comment: 0xb8000000 is a common way of referring to b800:0000 in x86 real-mode (i.e. 16bit) compilers, though.